# Convert logical relational expression to / from disjunctive and conjunctive forms?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

I would like to convert logical relational expressions in disjunctive form, e.g.,

$$(x \lt -1) \lor (-1 \lt x \lt +1) \lor (x \gt +1)$$

into conjunctive form, e.g.,

$$(x \ne -1) \land (x \ne +1)$$

I have some machinery in place that converts a logical relational expressions in disjunctive form into a union of intervals:

```
ClearAll[mxInterval];                                                                             

mxInterval::unrecognized = "The expression `` is not an Inequality, Less, LessEqual, GreaterEqual\
 or Greater operator or the logical Or of one or more of the operators.";                         

mxInterval[HoldPattern[Inequality[valueLeft_, ropLeft_, var_, ropRight_, valueRight_]]] :=        
    mxInterval[ropLeft, valueLeft, valueRight, ropRight];                                         

mxInterval[(rop:(Less|LessEqual))[var_, value_]] :=                                               
    mxInterval[LessEqual, "-∞", value, rop];                                            

mxInterval[(rop:(Greater|GreaterEqual))[var_, value_]] :=                                         
    mxInterval[rop, value, "∞", GreaterEqual];                                          

mxInterval[HoldPattern[Or[x__]]] :=                                                               
    Or @@ Replace[HoldComplete[x], elem_ :> mxInterval[elem], {1}];                               

mxInterval[expr_] := (Message[mxInterval::unrecognized, expr]; Return $fail;)                     

mxIntervalSymbol[op_, side_] := Switch[                                                           
    op,                                                                                           
    Less|Greater, Switch[side, l, "[", r, "]"],                                                   
    LessEqual|GreaterEqual, Switch[side, l, "(", r, ")"]];                                        

mxInterval /: MakeBoxes[mxInterval[ropLeft : (Less|LessEqual|Greater|GreaterEqual),               
                               valueLeft_, valueRight_,                                       
                               ropRight : (Less|LessEqual|Greater|GreaterEqual)], form_] :=   
    RowBox[{mxIntervalSymbol[ropLeft, l], MakeBoxes[valueLeft, form], ",",                        
            MakeBoxes[valueRight, form], mxIntervalSymbol[ropRight, r]}];
```

Using `mxInterval` on the sample expression produces a disjunction of intervals,

```
In[]: mxInterval[x < -1 || -1 < x < +1 || x > +1]

Out[]: Or[mxInterval[-∞,LessEqual,Less,-1],
          mxInterval[-1,Less,Less,+1],
          mxInterval[+1,Greater,GreaterEqual,∞]
```

which display as:

$$(-\infty, -1] \cup [-1,+1] \cup [+1,+\infty)$$

or, as the number line: oops, which is actually of $(-\infty,-1] \cup [+1,+1\infty)$:

[image: NumberLine]

(*Note*: Maybe I should produce Union instead of Or here. Would that eliminate the needs for a `MakeBoxes` definition for `Or[mxInterval ..]`? The only use for that function is to get the $\cup$ operator instead of $\lor$ in the display).

What I would really like is the function `mxInterval[Or[mxInterval ..], And]` which would take the disjunctive form of intervals and produce the conjunctive form. And, of course, `mxInterval[And[mxInterval ..], Or]` that would do the reverse.

If I were using a more procedural language, I would sort and then iterate over the intervals constructing the result along the way. However, I feel like the best way to implement the function in Mathematica is to rely heavily on pattern matching, but I'm having trouble formulating a solution using that paradigm.

Or, maybe there is a Mathematica incantation that will do the conversion on the original logical relational expression? That would be sweet.

Comment: This works for your simple example. Might not generalize well though, I'm not sure. `In[27]:= BooleanConvert[! Reduce[! ee], "CNF"]

Out[27]= x != -1 && x != 1`

Comment: That works for my current test cases, but `BooleanConvert` seems to ignore the form specification for `"DNF"` and `"CNF"`: `BooleanConvert[!Reduce[!result]]` produces the same result as `BooleanConvert[!Reduce[!result], "DNF"]` and `BooleanConvert[!Reduce[!result], "CNF"]`. Specifying `"NAND"` and `"NOR"` does produce the expected results. I'd like to try to understand why this produces the CNF form and add a few more test cases.

Comment: I suspect "DNF" is a default form. From the point of view of basic logic, a statement of the form `a AND b` with (a,b) both atomic is already in DNF, trivially, as an OR with but one clause. obviously it is also in CNF. This may explain the behavior you note.